# Filter garbage value in c

Tags: c

I want to print only the values that are present in an array. But it also shows the garbage values.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(){
  int arr[12];
  int i;

  arr[0] = 1;
  arr[1] = 2;
  arr[2] = 3;
  arr[4] = 5;

  for(i = 0; i<12;i++){
      if(arr[i] == '\0')
      {
        printf("\nNull");
      }
      else
        printf("\n %d",arr[i]);
   }

}
```

====== OUTPUT ======

```
1
2
3
Null
5
1
-2139062272
Null
-13136
Null
Null
Null
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.065 s
Press any key to continue.
```

How can I filter all the garbage values and only show the initialized value? Or, how can I clear all the garbage values?

Comment: If you don't initialize the array, it contains random garbage. If you don't want that, then initialize all of the elements in the array. If you don't, then count on getting garbage back when you use them.

Comment: Define "garbage value" first. For example, if the valid range is not less than 0, you can initialize the array all with a negative int (say, -1), then assign some values to some entries, and then you can filter the "garbage value" with a condition `<0`.

Comment: And if you attempt to *access an uninitialized value* you invoke *Undefined Behavior* in your code, the reliable operation of your program ceases, and anything can happen between appearing to work normally or SegFault'ing... You can avoid these problems by remembering to initialize all your variables to begin with, e.g. `int arr[12] = {0};` and `int i = 0;`. If you always initialize, you will never accidentally access an uninitialized value.

Comment: there's no such thing as a not present value. all the values are present.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I filter all the garbage value and only show the initialized value.

There's nothing that distinguishes a "garbage value" from an actual value in the array unless you have define a certain rule for what a garbage value is, otherwise, an integer is an integer.

> How can I clear all the garbage values.

Again, unless you have a rule for what a garbage value is, your alternative choice is to `memset` the array with a pre-desired value, that is initialize all the value in the array with one value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[12];
    memset(arr, '\0', sizeof arr);
   /* This fills arr with the null character */
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can zero out your array as such

```
int arr[12] = {0};
```

Comment: @M.M Good alternative, I'll add that!

Answer (score 1):

You could make somewhat of an [option type](https://www.wikipedia.com/en/Option_type) or nullable type  using structs, and then set them as initialized / uninitialized. If you must make full use of the integer range (thus cannot devote say, 0, to being uninitialized), then something along these lines would have to be used anyways. Many functional programming languages provide nullable types, but here's how you could implement something like it in C using macros.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// Value of uninitialized
#define NOTHING 0
// Convert from MaybeType to Type
#define SOME(x) x.value
// Check if whether MaybeType is Nothing (handle cases elsewhere)
#define MATCH(x) !!x.init
// Keep as MaybeType, but set to a non-Nothing value
#define LET(x, y) do { x.value = y; x.init = 1; } while (0)
// The do/while is for handling semicolon issues with multiple statements

// MaybeType structure and typedef
typedef struct {
    char init;
    int value;
} MaybeInt;

int main(){
    // Here we have to initialize our MaybeType to Nothing
    MaybeInt arr[12] = {{NOTHING, 0}};
    int i;

    LET(arr[0], 1);
    LET(arr[1], 2);
    LET(arr[2], 3);
    LET(arr[4], 5);

  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      // Handle the cases where MaybeType is/isn't Nothing
      if (!MATCH(arr[i])) {
          printf("Null\n");
      } else {
          printf("%d\n", SOME(arr[i]));
      }
   }
}
```

Note that 90% of the time, you can get by with something much simpler like setting all values to a dedicated uninitialized value via memset such as in Miket25's solution. But in the odd case that you cannot- you'll need to store extra data to indicate whether its initialized or not, as I did above.